# $T_{H^∗} ◦T_H : H → H^{∗∗}$ is a bijective linear isometry and coincides with the canoncial embedding $J : H → H^{∗∗}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, isometry

I have to show the following:

> The composition $T_{H^∗} ◦T_H : H → H^{∗∗}$ is a bijective linear isometry and coincides with the canoncial embedding $J : H → H^{∗∗}$. Here H is an arbitrary $\mathbb K$−Hilbert space and $T_H : H → H^∗$ denotes the map of the theorem of Riesz-Fischer, identifying $H$ with $H^∗$ in a canonical way.

How can I show that the composition coincides with J? That the composition is bijective and linear, is actually clear. But isometry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to show $J h = T_{H^*}(T_H(h))$ for all $h \in H$. This is an equation in $H^{**}$, thus it is sufficient to show
$(J h)(h^*) = T_{H^*}(T_H(h))(h^*)$
for all $h \in H$ and $h^* \in H^*$.

By definition of $J$ we have $(J h)(h^*) = h^*(h)$.
By definition of $T_{H^*}$,
we find $T_{H^*}(T_H(h))(h^*) = (T_H(h), h^*)_{H^*}$.
The definition of $T_H$ implies
$h^*(h) = (h^*, T_H h)_{H^*}$.

Altogether, this shows $J h = T_{H^*}(T_H(h))$. Since $J$ is a bijective linear isometry, the same holds true for $T_{H^*}(T_H(h))$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! That helped me a lot to understand the way how to prove similar statements. Great!